# Updating useContext and Redux at the same time is clearing Redux state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-context

In my application I am using both Redux and useContext for state management. I noticed that dispatching an action to redux to update state and updating useContext at the same time is causing Redux state to clear out. Almost seems like a re-render is happening under the hood upon updating my context. Does updating useContext re-render components??

[image: updating state code]

Removing the line to update useContext state in the code gets rid of the issue. The issue has to be with updating the context.

Comment: Why would re-rendering cause your redux state to clear? Redux state is global.

Comment: It's a micro frontend architecture, I assume that could play a role in it clearing out.

Comment: One wonders why you're using redux to manage your global state if it's not global.